# Sound problem with Toshiba Satellite L35-SP1011

Tags: 10.04, video, sound, ati

I've installed *Ubuntu 10.04* on a **Satellite L35-SP1011** and there's no sound.

Actually I have many video problems cause I had to disable effect because when it had effect activated, laptop got frozen many times.

I saw this problem but in older Ubuntu versions and tried some fixes without success. Any idea on how to solve my audio and video problems?

I've tried these instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver without success. My video card is a ATI Express 200M.

lspci output

```
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-ISA Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-PCI Bridge (rev 80)
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RC410 [Radeon Xpress 200M]
```

complete lspci output at http://pastebin.com/AVk1WWQt

I have solved this by editing `/etc/modprobe/alsa-base.conf` in Ubuntu 10.10 and added

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus
```

Now I'm working on video, I added xorg-edgers ppa, updated and upgraded without big difference... it's working better but without transparency.

Comment: lspci output: http://pastebin.com/AVk1WWQt

Comment: always add more info to your question so it doesn't get lost in a comment, thanks!

Comment: sorry i don't know how to edit my initial post. But thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

(Solution proposed by OP on the question body seems to work)

Edit `/etc/modprobe/alsa-base.conf` with your favorite text editor and add the following line to it so that the correct sound module is loaded:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus
```

After this your sound card should start working.